# Questions about DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance, dbcc, plan-cache, query-performance

I used spAskBrent for troubleshooting a SQL Server 2005 performance issue.

I found the problem was someone had ran DBCC FREEPROCCACHE. It caused low performance (very low PLE) on my database and queries to time out.

How can I find out who ran the query to free the plan cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to locate this within the `default trace` for SQL Server, if it is still enabled on the instance. One of the events captured is the `Security Audit: Audit DBCC Event`, can read more on the event [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188234(v=sql.90).aspx).

If you find the default trace is enabled the following [query from MSSQLTips.com article to find when DBCC were executed](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3445/using-the-sql-server-default-trace-to-audit-events/):

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260)

SELECT @path=path FROM sys.traces WHERE is_default = 1

--Security Audit: Audit DBCC CHECKDB, DBCC CHECKTABLE, DBCC CHECKCATALOG,
--DBCC CHECKALLOC, DBCC CHECKFILEGROUP Events, and more.
SELECT TextData, Duration, StartTime, EndTime, SPID, ApplicationName, LoginName  
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
WHERE EventClass IN (116) AND TextData like 'DBCC%CHECK%'
ORDER BY StartTime DESC
```

Comment: I tested this and it works!